# What is the capacity of the entrance?

Tags: delve

I'm playing [*Delve* by Anna Blackwell](https://blackwellwriter.itch.io/delve-a-solo-map-drawing-game) and certain things like *Treasury*, *Stockpile*, *Rune of Greed* reference a maximum capacity for *Resources* and *Trade Goods*.  Both *Treasury*, *Stockpile* increase this maximum, and *Rune of Greed* gives a consequence for exceeding your capacity.  As far as I can tell the rules do not seem to mention capacity aside from in passing.

There are a number of things I can't find answers to in the rules.  However most of them I can just resolve myself using my judgement.  However one thing I feel like I can't resolve on my own is the starting capacity.  You get 20 of each material to start so I assume it's at least 20.  But this really feels like something that should be mentioned in the rules, I just can't find it at all.

Answer (score 8):

The rules indeed do not state this.  However the intention is for the starting capacity to be 50 of each.

Anna Blackwell has answered this in a FAQ post on the Blackwell Games discord:

[image: Screenshot of the FAQ from discord]

> AnnaBlackwell 11/12/2020
>
> FAQ:
>
> Q: Starting Maximum Resource and Trade Goods Supply
> A: 50 of each